# How to display random data with Jstl c:forEach?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm trying to display 2 random products to the user when he visits a product page he has previously selected. Kind of like a suggestion box.

To accomplish this I'm using `<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" begin="0" end="1" step="1" varStatus="iter">`

It works fine at displaying the first two products but it is very limited because it will always display the same two products (the first and  the second).

How can I give the tag a boost and make it smarter? I want the program to display 2 different products every single time... Something like `first-second` `third-fourth` and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *How can I give the tag a boost and make it smarter?*

You're making a conceptual mistake. JSTL is for presentation, not for logic. Tags/EL should basically be kept "dumb" and just present the already-prepared model. It's the model-preparing Java code who's responsible for the real logic, usually (in)directly executed by a servlet.

You should focus on the Java code responsible for preparing the `${categoryProducts}` variable. It's exactly that code which has to be altered to "make it smarter". It's exactly you who has to add "smartness" to the code. There's no magic, there's just logic.

Easiest would be to use [`Collections#shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) before putting `${categoryProducts}` in the request scope. For example:

```
List<CategoryProduct> categoryProducts = categoryProductService.list();
Collections.shuffle(categoryProducts);
request.setAttribute("categoryProducts", categoryProducts);
```